Blazor Cannot provide a value for property
I am very new to Blazor and I am just trying to create a basic CRUD app that calls an API.
The error I'm getting is:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
'peopleService' on type 'PeopleUI.Client.Pages.People.PeopleList'.
There is no registered service of type
'PeopleUI.Client.Services.IPeopleService'.

this is my program.cs file in the client project
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using PeopleUI.Client.Services;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("api", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPeopleService, PeopleService>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();

this is my service:
public interface IPeopleService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPeopleAsync();

    Task<Person?> GetPersonById(Guid id);

    Task<bool> AddPerson(Person person);

    Task DeletePerson(Guid id);

    Task<bool> UpdatePerson(Person person);
}

public class PeopleService(IHttpClientFactory factory) : IPeopleService
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPeopleAsync()
    {
        using var client = factory.CreateClient("api");
        var respose = await client.GetAsync("/people");
        var people = await respose.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Person>>();
        return people;
    }

    public async Task<Person?> GetPersonById(Guid id)
    {
        using var client = factory.CreateClient("api");
        var respose = await client.GetAsync($"/people/{id}");
        return await respose.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Person>();
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        using var client = factory.CreateClient("api");
        var content = GetContent(person);
        var respose = await client.PostAsync("/people", content);
        return respose.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    private static StringContent GetContent(Person person)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person),
            Encoding.UTF8, 
            MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
        return content;
    }

    public async Task DeletePerson(Guid id)
    {
        using var client = factory.CreateClient("api");
        await client.DeleteAsync($"/people/{id}");
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        using var client = factory.CreateClient("api");
        var content = GetContent(person);
        var respose = await client.PutAsync($"/people/{person.Id}",content);
        return respose.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
}

and this is my view:
@page "/people-list"
@using PeopleUI.Client.Services
@using PeopleUI.Client.Models
@inject IPeopleService peopleService

<h3>PeopleList</h3>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    @if (People is not null)
    {
        @foreach (var person in People)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@person.LastName</td>
                <td>@person.FirstName</td>
                <td>@person.Email</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </thead>
</table>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<Person>? People { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        People = await peopleService.GetPeopleAsync();
    }

}

Can someone help me figure out why i am getting this error as you can see i am registering IPeopleService

I don't know if this is the correct answer but when I moved all of this to the server project it seemed to work.
